# vpn connection via node.js

Tags: node.js, database-connection, vpn, vertica

I am using node-vertica node.js library to connect to and run my SQL queries on HP Vertica database. The problem is that my app is hosted on a different network than the Vertica database. I need to connect to via VPN to network1 so that my node.js app could work properly, but since Vertica is on network2, I am unable to reach the Vertica database from my app. I am not sure about how to go around the networking aspect of this.

I was wondering if there is a way to connect to VPN via node.js (to acces network2) while I am on VPN1

I hope i explained my question well as i am not sure about the networking aspect of this

I don't have any code since it is a high level design question as such.

Comment: Hey @Rookie, did you get the soltuion for your problem?